# Is there an extension to allow members voted into certain roles (e.g. director, communication director...)?

Tags: drupal, roles

Is it possible to have an election of a group within CiviCRM.

Goal: 
elect users to hold certain roles within a group (e.g. editor, communication director...) and thusly:

1. allow members to vote
2. use certain rules to promote a user to a certain role (e.g. absolute majority...)
3. Roles are effective on the Drupal side, where the user now holds (or holds no longer) a certain role within a group

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe such an extension exists for CiviCRM.  However, there IS an [Election module](https://www.drupal.org/project/election) for Drupal, along with [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi), which I haven't used.  You could use CiviMember-Role sync to grant a role to members that allows them to vote, satisfying your first question.

You may be able to use Drupal Rules based on the outcome of the election - it appears Voting API supports this, not sure about Election module.  This would satisfy parts 2 and 3 of your question.